# try catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, error-handling

My project consists of a little icon moving over a grid with dimensions 25 by 20. I know I can do this easily with a few if/else blocks, but I want to learn more about error handling.

What I was thinking was using a try catch, but it doesn't catch the array index out of bounds exception or any `Exception` at all: it does not return "error" or the positions, so it never goes to the catch block.

I was thinking something like this pseudocode:

```
try {
    // Code
} catch(The exception) {
   x - 1 or + 1
}
```

Actual code:

```
 public void tick() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    try {
        int x, y;
        x = rand.nextInt(3) + (-1); //Slumpar fram en siffra (-1, 0, 1)
        y = rand.nextInt(3) + (-1); 
        setPosition(new Point((int)getPosition().getX()+x,(int)getPosition().getY() + y));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    System.out.println("x: " + getPosition().getX());
    System.out.println("y: " + getPosition().getY());
}

public String type() {
    return "Dummy";
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `setPosition` and `new Point(int, int)`? It seems as though no exception is being thrown.

Comment: As @Mureinik said, you could have no Exception thrown. You could also try to just throw a new exception manually inside the `try{ }` block to see you catch functioning

Comment: I don't even see an array here.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception doesn't sound like an exception that should be caught. If it occurs, it suggests something seriously wrong with the program.

Comment: You need something to throw in order to have something to catch. You'll need to manually code in these throw clauses yourself into your new Point() or setPosition() methods. ( x > 25 )  throw new Exception()

Comment: It's a grid array, the grid can go up to 25/20 but the code has now error handling atm if it goes over 25/20, I know it's possible to do with if(x==24) { x-1 } else { x = rand.nextInt(3) + (-1); }

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't see an array anywhere in your code, so that's maybe why the try block isn't catching anything (I assume there is an array in one of the called methods?). Also, you really, really shouldn't allow your program to read outside the bounds of an array. That's just bad design. That being said, here is how you would catch the exception in the clearest way I can think of:

```
try {
    array[index] = someValue;
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
    handleTheExceptionSomehow(exception);
}
```

Or do as @Peerhenry suggests and just throw a new Exception if the indices aren't correct, which would be a much better design.

Answer (score 4):

Putting code within a try catch block only makes sense if one or more methods inside can throw exceptions. You can throw an exception like this:

```
public static void setPosition(int x, int y) throws Exception
{
    if(x<0 || y<0) throw new Exception("coordinate components must be greater than zero");
    else...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 try {
                //code related  something to array
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {

            }
```