# How to stop Incessant crash on search filter in Android recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-search

I have been struggling to stop an index out of bounds exception crash every single time I do a search in a searchview. I tried a couple of things listed online :
[on search getting array out of index bound exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236319/on-search-getting-array-out-of-index-bound-exception)

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1040119/Android-app-is-crashing-with-Index-out-of-range-is

but nothing helped so far. The issue is something specific to my code, just can't figure out what's the issue.

Here's my crash report:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.dev, PID: 12873
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:0).state:146 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{3135a5 VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1440,66822 #7f09023b app:id/search_guests_recycler_view}, adapter:com.test.searchGuests.SearchGuestListAdapter@5ea4d7a, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@eba592b, context:com.test.SearchGuestActivity@6eb13
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5923)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1293)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:340)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
```

Here's my adapter code:
https://pastebin.com/fd80ccwF

and my activity code:
https://pastebin.com/wJHT1q9H

and presenter code:
https://pastebin.com/aKn0TFpz

here's my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_new_guest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="0dp">


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:paddingBottom="17dp"
                    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/white">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nav_back_btn"
                        style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24px"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/search_guest_main_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/past_guests"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.RidleyGrotesk.Medium"
                        android:textColor="#de000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"

                        />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:textColor="#a5a6b8"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Graphik.Semibold"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:text="@string/search_past_guests"/>
                <SearchView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/search_guest_list"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="#f6f6f6"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="@string/search_past_guests"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/info_scrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               >

               <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/search_guests_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_past_guest" />
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/no_match_relativelayout"
                        android:visibility="gone">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="No match found"
                            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/no_match_textview"
                            />
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor"
                            android:layout_below="@id/no_match_textview"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
               </RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any idea what I could be missing or not doing correctly, that it always crashes with ":java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:0)."(sometimes 16 or some other number, usually happens when i type in the searchview and the filter searches through the matching characters)

Happy to share more code or explain in detail if necessary. Have been struggling with this for days ,but no luck :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220771/recyclerview-inconsistency-detected-invalid-item-position

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936890/try-catch-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: checkout filter result u r getting and use debug to get how many no of result u r getting and how many count ur adapter gets, i think there is problem with ur filter result saving code or adapter

Comment: Ashu Kumar, thanks for your response! Can you check out my adapter and activity code and explain with respect to my code in the answer section. I tried everything, including debugging for the last few days and still couldn't this to stop crashing

Comment: I think you should remove `mSearchGuestListResponseListFiltered = filteredList;` (line 234) from your adapter code. Also, I can't understand why are you calling `notifyItemChanged()` in `getItemId()` and `onBindViewHolder()` methods.

Comment: @MirMiladHosseinyThanks so much for your response! That fixed it. Can you copy paste your response in the answer section so I can give you the bounty + mark your answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with `Filter` implementation. You are updating `mSearchGuestListResponseListFiltered` in the `performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)` method and it's source of the error. You must update your list in `publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)` method. So you must remove `mSearchGuestListResponseListFiltered = filteredList;` (Line 234)  from your adapter code. 
In addition, you called `notifyItemChanged()` method in `getItemId()` and `onBindViewHolder()` methods. I think it's wrong implementation as well and you should remove them.

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer! It doesn't allow me to award the bounty for the next 8 hours ( i guess theres a 24 hours min limit before awarding it), will award it in the next 8 hours :)

Comment: any idea about this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60254228/how-do-you-display-24-hour-time-format-in-hourly-increments-on-a-time-slider-in ( just a UI question atm)